# Postman - Compare two responses ignoring order and some specific properties

Tags: json, postman

I have two responses that I need to compare, ignoring the order and focusing if the property is there with the same value. Also, ignoring some specific properties as well (which contains in response 1 but should not be in response 2).

I've already tried with deep equal, but it's not what I wanted

-> To save the first response in a global variable:

```
pm.globals.set("response1", pm.response.json());
```

-> To compare in the second response:

```
pm.test("Compare responses", function(){    
    pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.deep.equal(pm.globals.get("response1"));
});
```

Edit: The responses also contain an array of objects

Comment: show what response1 and response looks a like?

Comment: Hi! Let's say the difference would be a single property called {"name": "teste"}, for example

Comment: Despite that, they're the same

Comment: it wont help unless you provide example, for response and response, we are not computers to auto understand the problems for more please read [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information, I just thought that the requests are not necessary for my solution. Therefore, I've figured out a solution. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution. On pre-request script:

```
pm.globals.set("loadAsserts", function loadAsserts(){
   let asserts = {};
   let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

   asserts.areEqual = function areEqual(actual, expected, objectName) {
        pm.test(`Actual ${objectName} '` + actual + `' matches Expected ${objectName} '` + expected + `'`, () => {
            pm.expect(_.isEqual(actual, expected)).to.be.true;
        });
    }

    asserts.areArrayOfObjectsEqual = function areArrayOfObjectsEqual(actual, expected, objectName) {
        if (!_.isEqual(actual, expected)) {

            // Arrays are not equal so report what the differences are
            for (var indexItem = 0; indexItem < expected.length; indexItem++) {
                assert.compareArrayObject(actual[indexItem], expected[indexItem], objectName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // This fake test will always pass and is just here for displaying output to highlight that the array has been verified as part of the test run
            pm.test(`actual '${objectName}' array matches expected '${objectName}' array`);
        }
    }

    asserts.compareArrayObject = function compareArrayObject (actualObject, expectedObject, objectName) {
        for (var key in expectedObject) {
            if (expectedObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                assert.areEqual(expectedObject[key], actualObject[key], objectName + " - " + key);
            }
        }
    }

    return asserts;
} + '; loadAsserts();');

tests['Asserts initialized'] = true;
pm.globals.set("actualResponse", pm.response.json());`
```

Now, when I want to call it in a response:

```
asserts.areEqual(actualResponse.id, expectedResponse.id, "id");
```

Comment: you may like to have one liner `pm.expect([1, 2, 3]).to.include.members([1, 2]);` or
             `pm.expect(response1).to.have.members(resopnse);`